# Out of Memory Exception - Google Map GroundOverLay

Tags: android, google-maps, bitmap, out-of-memory

I'm trying to draw a picture on the google map. I'm using the latest version of google play services and checked a lot for this issue and couldn't find an answer.

Here's some code:

```
    BitmapDescriptor image = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.drawing_bg);
    LatLngBounds drawingBounds = new LatLngBounds(
                                   new LatLng(29.93530, 30.88324), 
                                   new LatLng(29.93609, 30.88329))
                                .including(new LatLng(29.93580, 30.88286))
                                .including(new LatLng(29.93563, 30.88374))
                                .including( new LatLng(29.93593, 30.88347))
                                .including(new LatLng(29.93561, 30.88298))
                                .including(new LatLng(29.93591, 30.88344))
                                .including(new LatLng(29.93563, 30.88301));
    GroundOverlay groundOverlay = mMap.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
     .image(image)
     .zIndex(2)

     .positionFromBounds(drawingBounds)
     .transparency((float) 0.0));

    final Marker currentLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(29.93530, 30.88324)).draggable(true));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(29.935431502437588,30.88327579200268), 20));
```

From LogCat:

```
    05-03 11:45:17.860: E/dalvikvm-heap(1115): Out of memory on a 67108880-byte allocation.
    05-03 11:45:17.860: I/dalvikvm(1115): "GLThread 8598" prio=5 tid=21 RUNNABLE
    05-03 11:45:17.860: I/dalvikvm(1115):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4284d580 self=0x5a559790
    05-03 11:45:17.860: I/dalvikvm(1115):   | sysTid=1502 nice=1 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1596223616
    05-03 11:45:17.860: I/dalvikvm(1115):   | schedstat=( 216011094 92043700 221 ) utm=19 stm=2 core=3
    05-03 11:45:17.860: I/dalvikvm(1115):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
    05-03 11:45:17.860: I/dalvikvm(1115):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:640)
    05-03 11:45:17.860: I/dalvikvm(1115):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:620)
    05-03 11:45:17.860: I/dalvikvm(1115):   at maps.s.h.a((null):-1)
    05-03 11:45:17.860: I/dalvikvm(1115):   at maps.cr.a.a((null):-1)
    05-03 11:45:17.860: I/dalvikvm(1115):   at maps.cr.a.a((null):-1)
    05-03 11:45:17.860: I/dalvikvm(1115):   at maps.z.aa.b((null):-1)
    05-03 11:45:17.860: I/dalvikvm(1115):   at maps.z.aa.a((null):-1)
    05-03 11:45:17.860: I/dalvikvm(1115):   at maps.z.bi.a((null):-1)
    05-03 11:45:17.860: I/dalvikvm(1115):   at maps.af.v.a((null):-1)
    05-03 11:45:17.860: I/dalvikvm(1115):   at maps.af.v.a((null):-1)
    05-03 11:45:17.860: I/dalvikvm(1115):   at maps.af.v.a((null):-1)
    05-03 11:45:17.860: I/dalvikvm(1115):   at maps.p.q.m((null):-1)
    05-03 11:45:17.860: I/dalvikvm(1115):   at maps.p.q.run((null):-1)
    05-03 11:45:17.875: W/dalvikvm(1115): threadid=21: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x412cc2a0)
    05-03 11:45:17.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1115): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 8598
    05-03 11:45:17.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1115): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    05-03 11:45:17.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1115):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
    05-03 11:45:17.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1115):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:640)
    05-03 11:45:17.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1115):     at         android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:620)
    05-03 11:45:17.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1115):     at maps.s.h.a(Unknown Source)
    05-03 11:45:17.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1115):     at maps.cr.a.a(Unknown Source)
    05-03 11:45:17.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1115):     at maps.cr.a.a(Unknown Source)
    05-03 11:45:17.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1115):     at maps.z.aa.b(Unknown Source)
    05-03 11:45:17.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1115):     at maps.z.aa.a(Unknown Source)
    05-03 11:45:17.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1115):     at maps.z.bi.a(Unknown Source)
    05-03 11:45:17.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1115):     at maps.af.v.a(Unknown Source)
    05-03 11:45:17.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1115):     at maps.af.v.a(Unknown Source)
    05-03 11:45:17.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1115):     at maps.af.v.a(Unknown Source)
    05-03 11:45:17.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1115):     at maps.p.q.m(Unknown Source)
    05-03 11:45:17.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1115):     at maps.p.q.run(Unknown Source)
    05-03 11:45:29.395: W/SurfaceView(1115): CHECK surface infomation creating=false formatChanged=false sizeChanged=false visible=false visibleChanged=true surfaceChanged=true realSizeChanged=false redrawNeeded=false left=false top=false
```

I would really appreciate any help

Comment: I think you may be experiencing the same problem I am. I've opened a bug report on the Google Maps Android API tracker: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7325

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be using images that are too large. You logcat suggests you try to allocate 67 MB, which is way too much for most of the devices.

**Edit:**

Maybe try using `TileOverlay` instead of `GroundOverlay` if you want to show images on a large area (city, country) and not have it pixelated when zoomed.

Comment: the image I'm trying to use is only 663KB and its resolution is 1223x1248. Can you please let me know if should be handled or not? I can reduce the image size, but I need the best quality for zooming in.

Also, this issue happens on Samsung S3 and Toshiba Thrive Tablet but not on the Samsung S3 Mini.

Comment: 1223x1248 image would be about 6MB in memory when put in drawable-nodpi or folder matching device density. Every pixel takes 4 bytes. If it is put in mdpi folder on xhdpi device it will be scaled to 24MB in memory. I'm not sure where did this 67MB come from. Is this the only code you have in Activity with map?

Comment: there's another overlay that is drawn programatically above the map and under the same image I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

These 67Mb you are seeing seem to be from a confirmed bug in google maps, see here for more info: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7325

It was fixed back in February (2015 for the record). It should be solved if you use the latest version of google maps.