# Out of memory in ground overlay concept in google map?

Tags: android, image, google-maps

In my application i displayed the image on google map by using ground overlay.And also displayed the map marker on this image.In my application i am using view pager to load the images.And bellow the view pager i displayed map.In this map i displayed image by using ground overlay concept and also adding marker on this image by using latitude and longitude.Now when i scroll the image clear the marker and the new marker by using latitude and longitude.By using the following method i displayed the image on the map.

```
         public void loadMap(){

             map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            //For memory issue..

              bitmap = (Bitmap)BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.categorymap);
              BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
              o2.inSampleSize=4;
              image=BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap);

//             BitmapDescriptor image = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.categorymap);
               GroundOverlayOptions groundOverlay = new GroundOverlayOptions()
              .image(image)
              .positionFromBounds(bounds)
              .transparency(0.1f)
              .anchor(0.1f, 0.5f);
              map.addGroundOverlay(groundOverlay);
              bitmap.recycle();

              map.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);
              map.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(true);
         }
```

And when i scroll the image i changed the marker by using following method.

```
 public void setData(final int pos)
 {
     if(arl_place.size()!=0)
     {
         txt_right.setText(arl_locationname.get(pos));
         txt_left.setText(arl_place.get(pos));
     }


     double f_lat=0,f_lang=0;
     try{
    JSONArray jarr=null;
    jarr=arl_mapins.get(pos);
     if(jarr.length()!=0 || !jarr.equals(null)){

     for(int i=0;i<jarr.length();i++){
         JSONObject job=jarr.getJSONObject(i);
         f_lat=Float.parseFloat(job.getString("mapLat"));
         f_lang=Float.parseFloat(job.getString("mapLang"));
         MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(f_lat, f_lang)).title(arl_place.get(pos));
         mapmarker=map.addMarker(marker);
       }

     }


     map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(f_lat, f_lang), 16)); 
     jamapins=arl_mapins.get(pos);
     strPlacename=arl_place.get(pos);
     map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener()
     {
          @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
         public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
            // if(arg0.getTitle().equals(arl_place.get(0)))  {  
            Intent intent=new Intent(getParent(),MapZoom_BigEatDrinkActivity.class);  
            Intent intent2=new Intent(intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));

             intent2.putExtra("pinvalues", jamapins.toString());
             intent2.putExtra("place",strPlacename);
             intent2.putExtra("position",pos);
             View view = MapTab.group.getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("notification",intent2).getDecorView();  
             MapTab.group.replaceView(view);
            // }
             return true;
         }

     });

 }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
 }
```

But my problem is when i scroll the images from first to last and last to first in view pager and back to previous screen and again go to view pager screen and again scrolling the images i am getting        Out of memory exception.I tried alot for this exception but i did not resolve this exception.And this exception also not getting in all devices like **galaxy nexus** and **samsung s4**.But i am getting this in some device like **samsung galaxy r**. And also upload the apk to playstore. In this application i integrated bugsense. so i am getting crash reports heavily.So please suggest me to do support all devices with out getting out of memory issue. Thanks In advance to all..

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using images that are too large.

*Use `TileOverlay` instead of `GroundOverlay` if you want to show images on a large area (`city, country`) and not have it pixelated when zoomed.*

From [out-of-memory-exception-google-map-groundoverlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16356296/out-of-memory-exception-google-map-groundoverlay) and [android-google-maps-groundoverlay-from-bitmap-appears-white](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20373728/android-google-maps-groundoverlay-from-bitmap-appears-white).

Comment: i am using 1205 by 695 resolution only i.e 388 kb and also i am using following code  bitmap = (Bitmap)BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.omnistar_hp_two);


            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
             o2.inSampleSize=4;
             image=BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap);

Comment: Yes but when you navigate to and fro, this size will increase that will cause OOM.